# JQuery - Remove tag Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove two `<script>` tags from a page dynamically, at the `document ready`.
Every tag has its own id;
I've tried to insert in the code:

```
$("#idPrimoScript").remove();
$("#idSecondoScript").remove();
```

but nothing happens...

Some ideas? Thanks

Comment: you can also include script after html body code.

Comment: Please show us the relevant html as well.  If the above code does not work (when run at `document.ready` as shown below) then there is something else causing the problem.

Comment: Can you post your your html code too?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I don't think removing the tags will remove the script, since it's already loaded.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Why are you removing the script tags?

Comment: @Archer you are correct, overriding functions is the only way to unload any script which is often messy

Comment: Thanks @A.Wolff.  I've learnt something new so I can go back to bed now until tomorrow :D

Comment: @A.Wolff: I guess there is another way to disable scripts, please check my answer below

Answer (score 1):

As I can understand from your question, you want to remove (actually disable) the scripts included in your 2 script tags.
a work around I usually used to make in these situations is to introduce a variable which will act as a flag or a passing signal.
let's say that I will create a global variable which will be the flage I will be using:

`var enableMySpecialScript = true`

as you can see, I initially set the value of this flag to true, and whenever I need to disable the special script inside my page, I set this flag to false, then inside my script file, i always check for the flag's value,so when it's only "true", the script will execute, meaning that when it's false the script will not run, which is exactly what you are asking for.

This way you don't have to mess up with removing stuff or altering functions, and from my experience with this solution, it's a clean and debuggable one :)

Comment: This is very good solution, but the file that I call is an external js, form another site.

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.example.com/myScript.js"> </script>

Comment: what is the behavior of this script? is it something that hooks itself at the beginning? or something that is triggered when some event is being fired?

Comment: no, it starts every page load, and is contained in the footer.php, along with another script.
In practice, I can not access the source of that file.
The script check the visit on a site, similar Google Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently (having not tried this myself beyond a simple proof script) the way to do this is to create another function with the same name.

See:

[How to override a function in another javascript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814550/how-to-override-a-function-in-another-javascript-file)

[JavaScript: Overriding alert()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729501/javascript-overriding-alert)

[Override jQuery functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536788/override-jquery-functions)

[Overriding a function in jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929426/overriding-a-function-in-jquery-plugin)